# Git migration from one server to other keeping Git mirror intact

Tags: git, git-mirror

I have a Git repository on remote server-R. There is a Git mirror between server-R and server-C. There are 10 other server which can clone code from Git master repository Server-R.

Server-R will scrapped soon and I need to move entire Git master repo from server-R to a new server-X. I have very limited knowledge of Git. What do I need to do to migrate the Git master repo from server-R to server-X keeping all the history checkin, Git mirror intact and all 10 server must be able to push and pull from new server-X git.

Comment: Is the master Git a "bare repo" or a standard one?

Comment: @halfer standard

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer sure I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a number of Git repositories, all the same, and none of them are bare repos. When you do a `git clone` operation, you are copying the whole thing, and this is sufficient.

So, do a clone on the new primary server X, and then replace all of the `remote` references on all machines from R to X. You can see what remotes you have on any local repo by using:

```
git remote -v
```

To reset a remote, assuming you're using the default name of `origin`:

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

I would suggest that once you have reset all the URLs on all satellite repos, you push a dummy commit to the main server, and then pull from all others, to ensure they are pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, This solution will help direct all server to the new server X however how do I ensure that the new server X has all the historic check in , branch merge details which are currently on server-R??

Comment: What do you mean by "check in"? Files are not checked in or out in Git in the way they were in, say, SourceSafe - everything is editable by everyone. Your clone will have the whole of the history of the original, including all branches and merges. If you are in doubt, take a file backup of the original project on the current main server before scrapping it.